# wcf serviceActivations could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, visual-studio-2010

Can anyone tell me about this error?

> system.serviceModel/serviceHostingEnvironment/serviceActivations
>   could not be found.

I'm trying to make WCF app in VS2010 on Windows 7.

Any resolution?

Comment: Duplicate of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739465/deploying-wcf-tutorial-app-on-iis7-the-type-could-not-be-found)

Comment: But don't forget to accept your answer Jinx, seems you are new in this place, if you don't accept your answer you will not get any answer to your question in the future !!!

Comment: I have the same problem and didn't understand why. Need to read more - but this tutorial works really well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx +1 for asking this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows Activation Service is a feature of Windows 2008 Server which allow you to host WCF services using non-HTTP transport protocol, it's an IIS replacement to host services, i do not know if you can run it on a Windows 7.

If you are developing a WCF service on a developer PC you do not need it. You can host your WCF service in a simple console application, in a local HTTP server (VS.NET HTTP) or a local IIS server.

Right click your WCF project in the solution explorer, open Properties, select the Web tab, you should find development servers options (to run it locally, on a remote IIS, or on WAS).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at following link

[Deploying WCF Tutorial App on IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2739465/deploying-wcf-tutorial-app-on-iis7-the-type-could-not-be-found/2741956#2741956)

hope this help to solve your problem.

Answer (score -2):

I change the framework version to .Net 4.5 and the error is gone.